# How to fix: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\php\ext\php_imagick.dll' - The specified module could not be found in Unknown on line 0?

Tags: php, windows, imagemagick, php-extension, php-5.6

**UPDATE:** I realized I need to install ImageMagick on the same server that PHP is running on, in addition to using the php_imagick.dll library. I've tried a series of different combinations of versions of the ImageMagick installer and the php_imagick.dll library to no avail. How do I know which version number of each I should use?

I'm running PHP 5.6.40 (non-thread-safe) on a Windows Server 2019 machine.
My PHP website seems to be working for the most part except when I run `php -m` in the command line I get the warning that the **php_imagick.dll** module could not be found.

When I run a test PHP file that calls `phpinfo()`, the **ImageMagick - php_imagick.dll** extension is not listed anywhere.

In my **php.ini** file I have the full path for my extensions directory:
[image: Extensions Directory Path]

I also have the extension for ImageMagick (php_imagick.dll) listed in the php.ini:
[image: ImageMagick extension]

ImageMagick (php_imagick.dll) is definitely in the extensions folder listed above:
[image: Extensions]

Why am I receiving the warning it was unable to load that library when I run `php -m` from the command line?

[image: Modules]

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your server uses another `*.ini` file to load or some permissions are incorrect.

1. Try to search other configuration files such as `php.ini-development` and uncomment the line containing your extension in each file.
2. Make sure your `php_imagick.dll` library is visible by your PHP-server.
3. Restart your PHP-server after any changes in configuration files.

Comment: There are no other php.ini files on this server (I verified with AstroGrep). It's a newish server and I just installed PHP a week ago. What do you mean by #2? (I have php_imagick.dll in my "C:\Program Files\php\ext" folder and my php.ini file has the correct reference to the "C:\Program Files\php\ext" path for extension_dir. How to restart the PHP-server between changes to the configuration file? (I currently run iisrestart in the command line.)

Answer (score 0):

refer to this doc, it helps me and solves. As, I am using Php 7.4

```
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-imagick-for-php-in-windows/
```